# Generating legacy tokens in Kubernetes 1.22+

Tags: kubernetes

I can find plenty of documentation on the fact that since Kubernetes 1.21, service account tokens are now no longer non-expiring, but are time and scope bound.

What I can't find anywhere is if there is still a way to generate a "legacy token" for an existing service account in Kubernetes 1.21+; that is, a token that lives for a very long time or forever.

Is this described anywhere in the Kubernetes documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this described anywhere in the Kubernetes documentation?

You can find the details [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/1205-bound-service-account-tokens/README.md#serviceaccount-admission-controller-migration).